# PHP: Effect of code after header("Location: abc.html")

Tags: php, http

Lets say, the code looks something like this:

```
if(!$test) {
  header("Location: somefile.html");
  ...some PHP code....
  header("Location: anotherfile.html");
}
```

Is *'some PHP code'* above executed? If yes, then what happens to further HTTP response(s) therein (eg.: the second 'header' statement in the code)?

Comment: Well it redirects to _somefile.html_ and stops. But I am curious about what happens in the background.

Comment: You can configure some browsers not to follow the redirection, so if you protect a secured page with that, well someone can still access the page... tricky

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes** - the code will be executed.

The `header()` will **configure the headers to be returned, not send them right away.**

- If there is **no output** between the 2
  calls, then only the **last one** will be
  taken into account.
- However, if you **output anything**
  before the second call, then the
  **headers will be sent**, and the second
  call will result in an error (headers
  already sent).

A classic mistake is : redirect and not `exit()` right after that, which can cause security problems.

Comment: Well, redirect followed by die()...precisely what I am doing!

Comment: Well then that's good ! What I do is use a self made function for this (something named `redirect($url)`) that will change the headers *and* exit. That way you only use this, never `header()`, and don't have to worry about forgetting `exit()`.

Answer (score 3):

the rule is when doing a header redirect put an `exit` right after:

```
if(!$test) {
  header("Location: somefile.html");
  exit;
  //wont ever run
  ...some PHP code....
  header("Location: anotherfile.html");
}
```

if you don't put the `exit` there is a chance that code following might run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 'some PHP code' will run. The `Location` header is just like any other header. It can only be sent if the script is done executing. Thus, any code in between, assuming there is no exit, *has* to be run before the header matters.

Answer (score 2):

some other code is executed.

header("Location: xxx");

doesnt stop execution of the code. and it might take some time for the browser to respond.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
$test = "Hi!";
header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com?t=" . $test);
```

This code takes my browser to: http://www.yahoo.com/?t=Hi!

Answer (score 2):

The code after `header("location")` is executed. You should use an `exit();` if you don't want that :)

The redirection IS performed directly by the way, so you probably won't see the effect of things below the first header.