# PHP parse error on first hit, then segmentation fault

Tags: apache, segmentation-fault, php

I am trying to bring to life an old website for demonstration purposes. I am stuck with a PHP parse error and I can't find what it's about!

Here is the error I get (apache log) the first time I hit the page:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:
parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `'('' in .../functions.php on line 4
```

(the line return is for readability only) I end up with a 500 error.

Here is the only line I get the second time I hit the page:

```
[notice] child pid 3734 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

This time I end up with a 324: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Here is the code in the `functions.php` file, **please** don't look at the code it's very old ;).

```
<?php

// GoTo
function GoTo($page)
{
    global $FullPath;
    @header('Location:'.$FullPath.$page);
    echo "<script language='Javascript'>
                window.location='$page';
                </script>";
}
```

Do you see the parse error I am missing??

Why do I get a segfault the second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a newer version of PHP than you were when the site first came into existence, and `goto` has (sadly) been a keyword since PHP 5.3. Rename your function (:

Comment: Ohh nice catch!! This is so stupid :p

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `goto` as function name.

*The goto operator can be used to jump to another section in the program*

Change name of the function.

Also keep in mind that you need to exit the script after `header('Location: xxx');` and make sure you don't have any output before that header.

Comment: You don't need to exit the script after the `header` call.

Comment: @Lusitanian yes you do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833790/php-effect-of-code-after-headerlocation-abc-html/5833812#5833812 Anyway as I said I'm putting up the website for demonstration purposes, so not online.

Comment: Well, not really; you should never have to terminate a script with `exit` or `die` unless you like untestable code and cthulu.